# Unserialize dados em CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Vendo que tenho o seguinte método:

**Controller**

```
public function get_objeto($permissao_id)
{
    if ($permissao_id == 0)
    {           
        $permissao_id = $permissao_id;
        $dados = $this->permissao->get($permissao_id);
        echo json_encode($dados, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
    else
    {
        $dados = $this->permissao->get_by_id($permissao_id);

        echo json_encode($dados, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
// get_by_id
public function get_by_id($permissao_id)
{       
    $result = array();
    $result = $this->get_data($permissao_id);       
    return $result;
}
// get_data
public function get_data($permissao_id)
{
    $this->db->select('id, nome, permissoes tree_funcao, grupo_id');
    $this->db->from($this->tabela);
    $this->db->where('id',$permissao_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $item = $query->row();      
    return $item;
}
```

E o seguinte retorno do banco de dados:

```
{"id":3,"nome":"teste","tree_funcao":"a:7:{i:0;a:9:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"1\";s:4:\"text\";s:9:\"Dashboard\";s:4:\"icon\";s:23:\"fa  fa-folder text-osun\";s:7:\"li_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"1\";}s:6:\"a_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":2:{s:4:\"href\";s:1:\"#\";s:2:\"id\";s:8:\"1_anchor\";}s:5:\"state\";O:8:\"stdClass\":4:{s:6:\"loaded\";b:1;s:6:\"opened\";b:0;s:8:\"selected\";b:1;s:8:\"disabled\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}s:6:\"parent\";s:1:\"#\";s:4:\"type\";s:5:\"grupo\";}i:1;a:9:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"2\";s:4:\"text\";s:14:\"Configura\u00e7\u00e3o\";s:4:\"icon\";s:23:\"fa  fa-folder text-osun\";s:7:\"li_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"2\";}s:6:\"a_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":2:{s:4:\"href\";s:1:\"#\";s:2:\"id\";s:8:\"2_anchor\";}s:5:\"state\";O:8:\"stdClass\":4:{s:6:\"loaded\";b:1;s:6:\"opened\";b:0;s:8:\"selected\";b:1;s:8:\"disabled\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}s:6:\"parent\";s:1:\"#\";s:4:\"type\";s:5:\"grupo\";}i:2;a:9:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"3\";s:4:\"text\";s:8:\"Usu\u00e1rio\";s:4:\"icon\";s:34:\"fa fa-angle-double-right text-osun\";s:7:\"li_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"3\";}s:6:\"a_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":2:{s:4:\"href\";s:1:\"#\";s:2:\"id\";s:8:\"3_anchor\";}s:5:\"state\";O:8:\"stdClass\":4:{s:6:\"loaded\";b:1;s:6:\"opened\";b:0;s:8:\"selected\";b:1;s:8:\"disabled\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}s:6:\"parent\";s:1:\"2\";s:4:\"type\";s:6:\"funcao\";}i:3;a:9:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"4\";s:4:\"text\";s:5:\"Criar\";s:4:\"icon\";s:20:\"fa fa-lock text-osun\";s:7:\"li_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"4\";}s:6:\"a_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:4:\"href\";s:1:\"#\";}s:5:\"state\";O:8:\"stdClass\":4:{s:6:\"loaded\";b:1;s:6:\"opened\";b:0;s:8:\"selected\";b:1;s:8:\"disabled\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}s:6:\"parent\";s:1:\"3\";s:4:\"type\";s:4:\"acao\";}i:4;a:9:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"5\";s:4:\"text\";s:6:\"Editar\";s:4:\"icon\";s:20:\"fa fa-lock text-osun\";s:7:\"li_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"5\";}s:6:\"a_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:4:\"href\";s:1:\"#\";}s:5:\"state\";O:8:\"stdClass\":4:{s:6:\"loaded\";b:1;s:6:\"opened\";b:0;s:8:\"selected\";b:1;s:8:\"disabled\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}s:6:\"parent\";s:1:\"3\";s:4:\"type\";s:4:\"acao\";}i:5;a:9:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"6\";s:4:\"text\";s:7:\"Excluir\";s:4:\"icon\";s:20:\"fa fa-lock text-osun\";s:7:\"li_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"6\";}s:6:\"a_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:4:\"href\";s:1:\"#\";}s:5:\"state\";O:8:\"stdClass\":4:{s:6:\"loaded\";b:1;s:6:\"opened\";b:0;s:8:\"selected\";b:1;s:8:\"disabled\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}s:6:\"parent\";s:1:\"3\";s:4:\"type\";s:4:\"acao\";}i:6;a:9:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"8\";s:4:\"text\";s:10:\"Visualizar\";s:4:\"icon\";s:20:\"fa fa-lock text-osun\";s:7:\"li_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"8\";}s:6:\"a_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:4:\"href\";s:1:\"#\";}s:5:\"state\";O:8:\"stdClass\":4:{s:6:\"loaded\";b:1;s:6:\"opened\";b:0;s:8:\"selected\";b:1;s:8:\"disabled\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}s:6:\"parent\";s:1:\"3\";s:4:\"type\";s:4:\"acao\";}}","grupo_id":1}
```

> Como posso `unserializar` somente a coluna `tree_funcao`, mantendo os demais campos como estão ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acessar a chave `tree_funcao`, deve primeiro utilizar um [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php), (*porque, pelo que pude perceber é um* `json`) que vai retornar um `array` ***associativo***, após isso acesse a chave `tree_funcao` e utilize [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unserialize.php) da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$data = '{"id":3,"nome":"teste","tree_funcao":"a:7:{i:0;a:9:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"1\";s:4:\"text\";s:9:\"Dashboard\";s:4:\"icon\";s:23:\"fa  fa-folder text-osun\";s:7:\"li_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"1\";}s:6:\"a_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":2:{s:4:\"href\";s:1:\"#\";s:2:\"id\";s:8:\"1_anchor\";}s:5:\"state\";O:8:\"stdClass\":4:{s:6:\"loaded\";b:1;s:6:\"opened\";b:0;s:8:\"selected\";b:1;s:8:\"disabled\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}s:6:\"parent\";s:1:\"#\";s:4:\"type\";s:5:\"grupo\";}i:1;a:9:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"2\";s:4:\"text\";s:14:\"Configura\u00e7\u00e3o\";s:4:\"icon\";s:23:\"fa  fa-folder text-osun\";s:7:\"li_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"2\";}s:6:\"a_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":2:{s:4:\"href\";s:1:\"#\";s:2:\"id\";s:8:\"2_anchor\";}s:5:\"state\";O:8:\"stdClass\":4:{s:6:\"loaded\";b:1;s:6:\"opened\";b:0;s:8:\"selected\";b:1;s:8:\"disabled\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}s:6:\"parent\";s:1:\"#\";s:4:\"type\";s:5:\"grupo\";}i:2;a:9:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"3\";s:4:\"text\";s:8:\"Usu\u00e1rio\";s:4:\"icon\";s:34:\"fa fa-angle-double-right text-osun\";s:7:\"li_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"3\";}s:6:\"a_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":2:{s:4:\"href\";s:1:\"#\";s:2:\"id\";s:8:\"3_anchor\";}s:5:\"state\";O:8:\"stdClass\":4:{s:6:\"loaded\";b:1;s:6:\"opened\";b:0;s:8:\"selected\";b:1;s:8:\"disabled\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}s:6:\"parent\";s:1:\"2\";s:4:\"type\";s:6:\"funcao\";}i:3;a:9:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"4\";s:4:\"text\";s:5:\"Criar\";s:4:\"icon\";s:20:\"fa fa-lock text-osun\";s:7:\"li_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"4\";}s:6:\"a_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:4:\"href\";s:1:\"#\";}s:5:\"state\";O:8:\"stdClass\":4:{s:6:\"loaded\";b:1;s:6:\"opened\";b:0;s:8:\"selected\";b:1;s:8:\"disabled\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}s:6:\"parent\";s:1:\"3\";s:4:\"type\";s:4:\"acao\";}i:4;a:9:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"5\";s:4:\"text\";s:6:\"Editar\";s:4:\"icon\";s:20:\"fa fa-lock text-osun\";s:7:\"li_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"5\";}s:6:\"a_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:4:\"href\";s:1:\"#\";}s:5:\"state\";O:8:\"stdClass\":4:{s:6:\"loaded\";b:1;s:6:\"opened\";b:0;s:8:\"selected\";b:1;s:8:\"disabled\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}s:6:\"parent\";s:1:\"3\";s:4:\"type\";s:4:\"acao\";}i:5;a:9:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"6\";s:4:\"text\";s:7:\"Excluir\";s:4:\"icon\";s:20:\"fa fa-lock text-osun\";s:7:\"li_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"6\";}s:6:\"a_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:4:\"href\";s:1:\"#\";}s:5:\"state\";O:8:\"stdClass\":4:{s:6:\"loaded\";b:1;s:6:\"opened\";b:0;s:8:\"selected\";b:1;s:8:\"disabled\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}s:6:\"parent\";s:1:\"3\";s:4:\"type\";s:4:\"acao\";}i:6;a:9:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"8\";s:4:\"text\";s:10:\"Visualizar\";s:4:\"icon\";s:20:\"fa fa-lock text-osun\";s:7:\"li_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"8\";}s:6:\"a_attr\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:4:\"href\";s:1:\"#\";}s:5:\"state\";O:8:\"stdClass\":4:{s:6:\"loaded\";b:1;s:6:\"opened\";b:0;s:8:\"selected\";b:1;s:8:\"disabled\";b:0;}s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}s:6:\"parent\";s:1:\"3\";s:4:\"type\";s:4:\"acao\";}}","grupo_id":1}';

$data_array = json_decode ($data, TRUE);
$tree_funcao = unserialize ($data_array['tree_funcao']);

print_r($tree_funcao);
```

todos os outros campos estão dentro do `array` é só utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
$data_array['id']; // id
$data_array['nome']; // nome
```

e assim por diante!

[***Exemplo Online Ideone***](https://ideone.com/bmK4zs)

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)
- [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: assim eu já fiz e vi que dá certo. Acontece que este array associativo está em um campo da tabela, porém os outros campos não são array. Então como posso retornar os outros campos também?

Comment: Então só fazer $data_array['id’] é assim por diante @WagnerFilho ... Entendeu.!?

Comment: @WagnerFilho resposta editada!

Comment: eu coloquei uma resposta baseada na sua, portanto, validei a tua resposta.

Eu só tenho uma dúvida, se puder me ajudar.
Como pode ver, dentro da chave `tree_funcao` em cada índice do array, existe um item, chamado `state`. É possível percorrer todos os índices e obter o valor `selected` do `state` de cada índice percorrido ?

`[state] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [loaded] => 1
                    [opened] => 
                    [selected] => 1
                    [disabled] => 
                )`

Comment: @WagnerFilho tem sim é só fazer um for e depois acessar `state->selected` ...

Comment: algo como `foreach ($item['tree_funcao'] as $tree_funcao => $item)
  {
   echo ($tree_funcao);
   //echo ($tree_funcao['state']['selected']);
  }`

Comment: `$tree_funcao['state']->selected` @WagnerFilho

Comment: bom dia, pode me ajudar com esta questão ?https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291566

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_data($permissao_id)
{
    $this->db->select('id, nome, permissoes tree_funcao, grupo_id');
    $this->db->from($this->tabela);
    $this->db->where('id',$permissao_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $item = $query->row_array();

    $item['tree_funcao'] = unserialize($item['tree_funcao']);       
    return $item;
}
```